# Bundler issue when running a ruby script

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am trying to run some older ruby script (with old ruby version) from within a ruby script. Here is a program:

#### old_ruby187.rb

```
#!/usr/ruby/1.8.7/bin/ruby
puts "Hello"
```

#### new_ruby230.rb

```
#!/usr/ruby/2.3.0/bin/ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup       # Code works if I comment this line
puts `old_ruby187.rb`
```

I get bundler load error. If I execute `./new_ruby230.rb`, it gives an error for the last `puts` command line.:

```
'require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
```

If I comment just `Bundler.setup` and run it, it works fine. Not sure if `Bundler.setup` tries to load something for `system` call. I need bundler for other gems used in `new_ruby230.rb` script.

Any help is appreciated.

***Update (02/22/2018):***
I ended up using ssh when calling old ruby script. Something like:

#### new_ruby230.rb

```
#!/usr/ruby/2.3.0/bin/ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
require "socket"
Bundler.setup
puts `ssh #{Socket.gethostname} old_ruby187.rb` # this worked!
```

Comment: Is the error stack from Bundler.setup method call ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're not supposed to require rubygems like that.  Bundler is there to manage your gems.  Remove that require statement (require "rubygems") and you should be good to go.

Comment: As I mentioned rubygems has nothing to do with, the code is having issues while running other version of ruby in a script - last `puts` line. I removed `require "rubygems"` and still same error. I required rubygems referring [this](http://bundler.io/v1.12/bundler_setup.html).

Comment: Have you run 'bundle install' in your terminal?

Comment: Yes, I can use gems. I just cannot run other version of standalone ruby script with `Bundler.setup`!

Comment: Are you using rbenv or rvm?  I feel like I'm not understanding you correctly.  What is the output of 'bundle install'?

Comment: No I am not using rbenv or rvm. Just to simplify, I can run any external (shell, pearl, etc) script or unix command using ticks or `system`, except for ruby script (which is using older ruby version). If I do not use `Bundler.setup`, the ruby script also get executed fine with `system` command. Does this makes sense now?

Comment: It seems like `Bundler.setup` is called for any script/command executed using ticks or `system` command. Is there option to turn that off?